# Being asked now to Activate Windows 10 after I installed a new CPU + MoBo

Tags: windows-10

Before I didn't have this but I got a new ASUS mobo and i3 CPU, and I now have a Activate Windows watermark on my screen and it won't let me activate with any code

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Was your Windows oem or retail? If OEM, the license key was tied to your old motherboard.

Comment: Microsoft considers that to now be a 'new computer'. Ring them & see if they are amenable. Sometimes you can just catch them in the right mood :)